# How to get the result of a command in a HERE_doc in Bash

Tags: bash, curl, heredoc, at-job

I'm using the `at` command to schedule a job in the future.

```
DoCurlAt () {
    if [ -n "${AuthToken:-}" ] ; then
        $4 << 'EOF'
curl -s -H "${AuthHeader:-}" -H "$1" --data-urlencode "$2" "$3"
EOF
        Exitcode=$?
    fi
    WriteLog Output Info "AT Output: $AtOutput Exitcode: $Exitcode"
}
```

How can I capture the result of the at in a variable called $AtOutput?

I tried with

```
AtOutput=$(bash $4 << EOF
curl -s -H "${AuthHeader:-}" -H "$1" --data-urlencode "$2" "$3"
EOF
)
```

But that does't really give any result.

Also tried with:

```
AtOutput=$(curl -s -H "${AuthHeader:-}" -H "$1" --data-urlencode "$2" "$3" | at "$4")
```

But I would prefer to use the HERE-doc.
The function is called with

```
DoCurlAt "$AcceptJson" "argString=$ArgString" "$ApiUrl/$ApiVersion/job/$JobUid/run" "$OneTime"
```

$OneTime ($4) could be for example "at 15:19 today" The output is mostly something like this:

```
job 7 at 2016-08-16 15:30
```

Comment: You can't capture the output of a job scheduled at a later time with `at`.

Comment: I don't want the output of the scheduled job.... it's quite obviopus that is impossible. I need the output of the at command.. Example 'job 7 at 2016-08-16 15:30'

Comment: What's the difference between the two branches of the `if` statement? It's hard to follow what your intent is. (By the way, read [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).)

Comment: The second part was for a curl without an auth header. I removed it from the example as it's not important here. Sry

Comment: I'd start by hard-coding the `at` command instead of including it as part of the 4th argument. `curl ... | at "$4"`.

Comment: Already tried with `AtOutput=$(curl -s -H "${AuthHeader:-}" -H "$1" --data-urlencode "$2" "$3" | at "$4")` but although the at is executed, I'm unable to catch the output of the at in the variable $AtOutput

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121067/discussion-between-willemdh-and-chepner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` writes to standard error, not standard output. Use the `2>&1` redirection to copy standard error to standard output first.

```
$ at_output=$( echo "cmd" | at "$when" 2>&1 )
```